# PHP: assigning random character before and after a number?

Tags: php, random, output, implode

How can I assign random character before and after the numbers? it gives me same random character when I run the script.

Here's a example code:

```
<?php
function randomChar($length = 1) 
{
    $str = ""; 
    $characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'));
    $max = count($characters) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
        {   
            $rand = mt_rand(0, $max);
            $str .= $characters[$rand];
        }  
        return $str; 
}

$test = "0123456789";

echo implode(randomChar(), str_split($test, 1));
?>
```

when I run the script above it gives me the output of:

```
Output: 0Y1Y2Y3Y4Y5Y6Y7Y8Y9
```

My desired output must be:

```
Output: 0A1V2J3Y4Z5Q6S7O8R9
```

can someone help me to figure it out? thank you :)

Comment: You're only calling the function once, so it will only return 1 random character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you only fetch a single random character and use it to join the characters together - this means that the same character will be used every time.

If you want to generate a new character for each delimiter, you will need to pass the input string into your function, something like this:

```
function insert_random_chars($str, $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGRSTUVWXYZ")
{
    // An array to hold the result
    $result = array();

    // The highest character index in the string
    $max = strlen($alphabet) - 1;

    // Loop the characters in the input string
    foreach (str_split($str, 1) as $char) {
        // Add the current character and a random character to the output array
        array_push($result, $char, $alphabet[mt_rand(0, $max)]);
    }

    // Join the output array together
    return implode('', $result);
}

echo insert_random_chars("0123456789");
```

[Example output](http://3v4l.org/oKvZ0):

> 0L1E2G3T4F5S6E7F8I9M

Note that this code doesn't do *precisely* what you want, but it should give you a push in the right direction ;-)

Comment: And additional +1 for making it shorter and more useful :)

Comment: there's another way to shorten the $alpabet= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRATUVWXYZ'; like $alpabet= [A-Z];?

Comment: @myel PHP doesn't have any sugar for ranges like this, but you can `implode(range())` or refactor it to use an array as the alphabet input

Answer (score 0):

When calling `randomChar()`, you need to specify the length of the random characters you want to generate. Otherwise, it will just create 1 random character (default values).

The [`implode()`](https://www.google.com/interstitial?url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php&sa=U&ei=iPJoUtoqhImtB4nYgagN&ved=0CBgQFjAA) function you are using will actually paste the (array) values from second parameter and make the first parameter as the 'glue'. As such, Even if your `randomChar()` returns more than 1 character, the strings will be repeated for every numbers you want to combine.

Example: 0ABC2ABC ... 8ABC9

What you need to do instead is:

1. Create an empty string to hold the resulting string.
2. Generate `randomChar()` to be as many as the test string (or -1 if you only want the characters to be between numbers).
3. For each of the numbers, concatenate the number and the random character and put it in the string from #1.
4. Print the result.

Code:

```
function randomChar($length = 1)
{
    $str = "";
    $characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'));
    $max = count($characters) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $rand = mt_rand(0, $max);
            $str .= $characters[$rand];
        }
        return $str;
}

$test = "0123456789";

$length = strlen ($test);
$combined = '';
$random_char = randomChar ($length);

for ($i = 0;$i < $length; $i++)
{
   $combined .= $test[$i] . $random_char[$i];
}


print $combined . "\n";
```

Sample output: [codepad](http://codepad.org/GwsSHLtY)